# Raise exception in python-fastApi middleware

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn, starlette

I am trying to validate token in fastapi middleware but this seems impossible. As i am thinking middleware needs to make next call although its not required. I am not able to find any good solution to handle token in one go in this python-fastapi backend. Any help is appreciated.

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def add_middleware_here(request: Request, call_next):
    token = request.headers["Authorization"]
    try:
        verification_of_token = verify_token(token)
        if verification_of_token:
            response = await call_next(request)
            return response
    except InvalidSignatureError as er:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401)
```

Comment: I don't find any mention that that it is possible. Though you may try responding with a custom response https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue. @TrickOrTreat

Answer (score 16):

You need to return a response. I'll show you how you can make it work:

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@app.middleware("http")
async def add_middleware_here(request: Request, call_next):
    token = request.headers["Authorization"]
    try:
        verification_of_token = verify_token(token)
        if verification_of_token:
            response = await call_next(request)
            return response
        else:
            return JSONResponse(status_code=403) # or 401
    except InvalidSignatureError as er:
        return JSONResponse(status_code=401)
```

Be aware that using this middleware implies that you don't have a login route on your API (for token generation).

Besides, you should consider using this dependency instead: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/

Another thing is that you can use [fastapi.status](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-status-code/) for your status code.

Answer (score 5):

See [JSONResponse API](https://www.starlette.io/responses/#jsonresponse) documentation.

```py
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@app.middleware("http")
async def errors_handling(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        return await call_next(request)
    except Exception as exc:
        return JSONResponse(status_code=500, content={'reason': str(exc)})
```