# FastAPI: reject a WebSocket connection with HTTP response

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi, asgi, starlette

In a FastAPI based Web app, I have a WebSocket endpoint that should allow connections only if some conditions are met, otherwise it should return an `HTTP 404` reply instead of upgrading the connection with `HTTP 101`.

As far as I understand, this is fully supported by the protocol, But I couldn't find any way to do it with FastAPI or Starlette.

If I have something like:

```py
@router.websocket("/foo")
async def ws_foo(request: WebSocket):
    if _user_is_allowed(request):
        await request.accept()
        _handle_ws_connection(request)
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404)
```

The exception isn't converted to a 404 response, as FastAPI's `ExceptionMiddleware` doesn't seem to handle such cases.

Is there any native / built-in way of supporting this kind of "reject" flow?

Answer (score 6):

Once a handshake is completed, the [protocol changes from `HTTP` to `WebSocket`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). If you attempted to raise an `HTTP` exception inside the websocket endpoint, you would see that this is not possible, or return an `HTTP` response (e.g., `return JSONResponse(...status_code=404)`), you would get an internal server error, i.e., `ASGI callable returned without sending handshake`.

### Option 1

Thus, if you would like to have some kind of checking mechanism before the protocol is upgraded, you would need to use a [`Middleware`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/), as shown below. Inside the middleware, you can't raise an exception, but you can return a response (i.e., `Response`, `JSONResponse`, `PlainTextResponse`, etc), which is actually how FastAPI [handles exceptions](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#install-custom-exception-handlers) behind the scenes. As a reference, please have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61358669/raise-exception-in-python-fastapi-middleware), as well as the discussion [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1304).

```
async def is_user_allowed(request: Request):
    # if conditions are not met, return False
    print(request['headers'])
    print(request.client)
    return False

@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    if not await is_user_allowed(request):
        return JSONResponse(content={"message": "User not allowed"}, status_code=404)
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

or, if you prefer, you can have `is_user_allowed()` method raising a custom exception that you need to catch with a `try-except` block:

```
class UserException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(message)

async def is_user_allowed(request: Request):
    # if conditions are not met, raise UserException
    raise UserException(message="User not allowed.")
    
@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        await is_user_allowed(request)
    except UserException as e:
        return JSONResponse(content={"message": f'{e.message}'}, status_code=404)
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

### Option 2

If, however, you need to do that using the `websocket` instance, you could have the same logic as above, but, instead, pass the `websocket` instance in `is_user_allowed()` method, and catch the exception inside the websocket endpoint (inspired by [this](https://indominusbyte.github.io/fastapi-jwt-auth/advanced-usage/websocket/)).

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(ws: WebSocket):
    await ws.accept()
    try:
        await is_user_allowed(ws)
        await handle_conn(ws)
    except UserException as e:
        await ws.send_text(e.message) # optionally send a message to the client before closing the connection
        await ws.close()
```

In the above, however, you would have to accept the connection first, so that you can call the `close()` method to terminate the connection, if exception is raised. If you prefer, you could use something like the below. However, that `return` statement insdie the `except` block would throw an internal server error (i.e., `ASGI callable returned without sending handshake.`), as described earlier.

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(ws: WebSocket):
    try:
        await is_user_allowed(ws)
    except UserException as e:
        return
    await ws.accept()
    await handle_conn(ws)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I'm *specifically* asking about a way to return with an HTTP response (typically indicating an error) *before* the handshake is completed and the connection is upgraded.

Comment: That is what has been demonstrated in the first option (using `@app.middleware("http")`).

Comment: The middleware approach doesn't work in my testing. Websocket requests are specifically routed around HTTP middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In some circumstances, you want to reply to an incoming Websocket upgrade request with a regular HTTP header. For instance, sometimes special headers are used to configure network routing in work balancers etc.

I took me some time to figure out, that the handlers for the different protocols seem to live on a more basic level with FastAPI. The handling of different protocols for routes seem to be propagated from the ASGI server (e.g. [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/)) to starlette to FastAPI. So in my case, the solution was to simply disable the Websocket protocol in uvicorn using `--ws none` or `ws="none"`). As a result, my regular route with `.get()` handler receives the websocket upgrade request and can reply with a HTTP header.

This is ok for my application, where FastAPI acts as a gateway and does not need to implement Websocket itself. Unfortunately, I don't know of a solution with this tech stack which handles mixed cases.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do using with a exception_handler on HTTP exceptions, and sending "websocket.http.response.start" signal directly to ASGI if websocket is not open yet.

(just tested on uvicorn==0.27.0 and fastapi==0.103.1)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.websockets import WebSocket
from fastapi.exception_handlers import http_exception_handler

app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(HTTPException)
async def custom_http_exception_handler(request, exc):
    if not isinstance(request, WebSocket):
        return await http_exception_handler(request, exc)
    websocket = request
    if websocket.application_state == 1:  # 1 = CONNECTED
        await websocket.close(code=1008, reason=str(exc))  # 1008 = WS_1008_POLICY_VIOLATION
        return
    headers = getattr(exc, "headers") or []
    await websocket._send({"type": "websocket.http.response.start", "status": exc.status_code, "headers": headers})
```