# How to catch or process RequestValidationError exceptions differently in a FastAPI middleware?

Tags: python, exception, fastapi, middleware, fastapi-middleware

How to correctly combine `RequestValidationError` exception handling functions:

```
@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
    response = prepare_response({}, g_ERROR__INCORRECT_PARAMS)

    return JSONResponse(content=response)
```

and the middleware code function:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        result = await call_next(request)

        res_body = b''
        async for chunk in result.body_iterator:
            res_body += chunk

        response = prepare_response(res_body.decode(), g_ERROR__ALL_OK)
    except Exception as e:
        response = prepare_response({}, g_ERROR__UNKNOWN_ERROR)

    return JSONResponse(content=response)
```

It is necessary that ONLY the `RequestValidationError` exception triggers the following function:

```
@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
```

and all other cases this function:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
```

Now the `response_middleware` function fires all the time and processes the result of `validation_exception_handler`, which violates the basic intent of the function.

When using `@app.middleware("http")` any exceptions disappear and even without `@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)` the code consistently generates `200 OK` and

```
    try:
        result = await call_next(request)

        res_body = b''
        async for chunk in result.body_iterator:
            res_body += chunk

        response = prepare_response(res_body.decode(), g_ERROR__ALL_OK)
    except RequestValidationError as e:
        response = prepare_response({}, g_ERROR__INCORRECT_PARAMS)
    except Exception as e:
        response = prepare_response({}, g_ERROR__UNKNOWN_ERROR)
```

also doesn't work at all after

```
result = await call_next(request)
```

no exceptions are thrown

How can this problem be solved?

On the one hand we need middleware code for different functions, on the other hand some exceptions (incorrect parameters, etc.) should be tracked before the intermediate code or inside it, but not deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-raise `RequestValidationError` exception in your middleware.

Try changing your middleware code as shown below:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        result = await call_next(request)

        res_body = b''
        async for chunk in result.body_iterator:
            res_body += chunk

        response = prepare_response(res_body.decode(), g_ERROR__ALL_OK)
    except RequestValidationError as e:
        raise # Re-raise exception!
    except Exception as e:
        response = prepare_response({}, g_ERROR__UNKNOWN_ERROR)

    return JSONResponse(content=response)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that would be to `raise` any `RequestValidationError` exceptions in your [custom `validation_exception_handler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804), and then catch them, using a `try-except` block around `await call_next(request)` in the middleware—please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76269047/17865804) (Options 1 and 2), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) (Option 4) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71256914/17865804) (Option 1) for complete working examples.

However, the most straightforward way might be to simply check the `status_code` of the `response`, and if the [HTTP response status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is in the range specified (e.g., between `400` and `599`, indicating a client or server error), or if it is just `422` (as you mentioned that only `RequestValidationError` exceptions  need to be processed differently from every other response/exception), then process the response accordingly. You might also benefit from looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804), when dealing with a `middleware` in FastAPI.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def custom_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    
    #if 399 < response.status_code < 600:
    if response.status_code == 422:
        # return Exception response as is
        return response
        
        # or return some custom response
        #return JSONResponse(status_code=422, content={"msg": "custom"})
        
    else: # do whatever
        return response
    

class Demo(BaseModel):
    content: str


@app.post('/')
async def main(demo: Demo):
    return demo
```